# ¿Cómo recupera el value de las <li>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql-server, visual-studio-2017, knockoutjs

Tengo dos listas de tipo `<ul>`

```
ListaA ----------> lista todo los productos

ListaB ----------> lista los productos seleccionados a comprar
```

Lo que quiero hacer es recuperar el value de las `<li>` seleccionadas para guardarlos en un array y guardarlos en la base de datos

```
<li value="4" style="list-style: none; width: 70%; margin: 6px; text-align: center; cursor: move; position: relative; z-index: 1; left: 0px; top: 0px;" class="list-group-item ui-sortable-handle" id="li">DELL</li>
```

Cargo la listaA de la siguiente manera:

```
self.ListaProductosA = ko.observableArray([]), 
    self.getListaProductosA = function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Producto/ListaProducto',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset = utf-8',
            success: function (data) {
                var html = '';
                $.each(data, function (key, item) {
                    self.ListaProductosA(data);
                    html += '<li value = ' + item.productoID + ' style="list-style:none; width:70%; margin:6px; text-align:center; cursor: move" class="list-group-item" id="li" >';
                    html += item.Descripcion;
                    html += '</li>';


                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        //Aplicar la función sortable a la lista con id listaConceptosA
                        // y conectarla con la lista de id listaConceptosB
                        $("#listaA").sortable({
                            connectWith: '#listaB'
                        });

                        //Aplicar la función sortable a la lista con id listaConceptosB
                        // y conectarla con la lista de id listaConceptosA
                        $("#listaB").sortable({
                            connectWith: '#listaA'
                        });
                    });

                });
                $("#listaA").html(html);     
            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert(err.status + " : " + err.statusText);
            }
        });
    }
```

Mi vista en index es la siguiente:

```
      <div id="listBox">
        @*<div id="contentDrag">*@
        <h5> Lista de productos</h5>
        <ul id="listaA" class="form-control">
          <li>item</li>
        </ul>
        @*</div>*@

        @*<div id="contentDrop">*@
        <h5> Lista de productos seleccionados</h5>
        <ul id="listaB" class="form-control">
          @*<li></li>*@
        </ul>
        @*</div>*@

      </div>
```

Comment: Seria bueno que puedas completar tu pregunta con un ejemplo de lo que has realizado. POr ejemplo estas utilizando jquery y knockoutJs? con cual de los dos tienes en la pantalla donde quieres realizar? como cargas la informacion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo que deseas es obtener un array de la lista sin utilizar el elemento **onclick** puedes hacer una función que te devuelva un array a partir del **id** de la lista. Por ejemplo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>JavaScript</title>

</head>
<body>
    <ul id="list">
        <li value="1">Elemento1</li>
        <li value="2">Elemento2</li>
        <li value="3">Elemento3</li>
        <li value="4">Elemento4</li>
    </ul>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function arrayFromList(id) {
            //Array con cada value:
            var dataValue = [...document.querySelectorAll(`#${id} li`)]
                .map(element => element.value);

            //Array con cada texto de la lista:
            var dataElement = [...document.querySelectorAll(`#${id} li`)]
                .map(element => element.innerText);     


            //console.log(dataValue);   // Array [1,2,3,4]
            //console.log(dataElement); // Array ["Elemento1","Elemento2","Elemento3","Elemento4"]

            return dataValue;
        }

        //Array que crearemos utilizando la función:
        var array = arrayFromList('list'); 

        console.log(array);

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

La función retorna un array, que dependiendo del array que retorne puede ser el **value** de cada elemento de la lista o también el **texto de cada elemento de la lista**.

La salida por consola dependiendo del array que retornes en la función sería el siguiente array:

```
Array(4) [1,2,3,4]
```

o

```
Array(4) [ "Elemento1", "Elemento2", "Elemento3", "Elemento4" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera, cada vez que selecciones un elemento de la lista, se ejecutará la funcion **añadirArray()**, en ella obtendremos el valor del elemento con **id** que deseemos, asignando ese elemento a una variable y luego haciendo un push a un array global. Por ejemplo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>JavaScript</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">   

    //Array global, irá almacenando todos los elementos.
    var array = [];

    function añadirArray(){
        var elemento = document.getElementById("li").value;
        console.log(elemento); //IMPRIME: 4

        //Metiendo el elemento en un array global, cada vez que se haga click, se añadirá al array.
        array.push(elemento);
        console.log(array); //IMPRIME EL ARRAY, INCREMENTARÁ CUANTOS MÁS CLICKS.
    }


  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li value="4" onclick="añadirArray()" id="li">DELL</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

De esta manera cada vez que hagamos click no se perderán los cambios, y el array irá aumentando, añadiendo a este el **value** de cada elemento de la lista que hagamos click.
Si quieres ver un ejemplo con dos listas, puede ser algo parecido a lo siguiente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>JavaScript</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">   

    //Array global, irá almacenando todos los elementos.
    var array = [];

    function añadirArray1(){
        var elemento = document.getElementById("li1").value;
        console.log(elemento); //IMPRIME: 4

        //Metiendo el elemento en un array global, cada vez que se haga click, se añadirá al array.
        array.push(elemento);
        console.log(array); //IMPRIME EL ARRAY, INCREMENTARÁ CUANTOS MÁS CLICKS.
    }
    function añadirArray2(){
        var elemento = document.getElementById("li2").value;
        console.log(elemento); //IMPRIME: 4

        //Metiendo el elemento en un array global, cada vez que se haga click, se añadirá al array.
        array.push(elemento);
        console.log(array); //IMPRIME EL ARRAY, INCREMENTARÁ CUANTOS MÁS CLICKS.
    }


  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li value="4" onclick="añadirArray1()" id="li1">Elemento 1</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li value="7" onclick="añadirArray2()" id="li2">Elemento 2</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

El resultado de la salida por la consola del navegador al pulsar varias veces el primer elmento de la lista y el segundo aleatoriamente sería algo parecido a lo siguiente:

```
7
Array [ 7 ]
4
Array [ 7, 4 ]
7
Array(3) [ 7, 4, 7 ]
4
Array(4) [ 7, 4, 7, 4 ]
7
Array(5) [ 7, 4, 7, 4, 7 ]
```

Comment: Los <li> no se les puede asignar el evento onclick, solo son arrastrados a la otra lista. ¿Habría otra forma de mandar a llamar la función cada vez que se agregue un <li> a la otra lista?