# ¿Como guardar en un array los datos que contiene un <li>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, visual-studio-2017

Tengo una lista de tipo `<ul>` y quiero recorrer esa lista para recuperar los datos que contiene cada `<li>` e ir guardandolos en un array

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cómo recupera el value de las <li>?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/306450/c%c3%b3mo-recupera-el-value-de-las-li)

Answer (score 0):

podrías hacerlo así:

```js
let lista = document.getElementById("elIdQueTengaLaLista");
let items = lista.getElementsByTagName("li");

for (let i=0; i<items.length; ++i) {
  // Aquí accedes a cada item de la lista así: items[i]
  // Por ejemplo si quieres leer el contenido de cada item, sería así
  items[i].innerHTML
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para lograr eso te propongo el siguiente código

```js
function getDataFromList(id) {
  let data = [...document.querySelectorAll(`#${id} li`)]
    .map(element => element.innerText);

  console.log(data);
}

getDataFromList('lista');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <ul id="lista">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
  </ul>

  <script src="aux.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Gracias a la función `querySelectorAll` puedes obtener todos los `li` al interior de un id dado, luego con el operador ... de spread y los corchetes conviertes lo encontrado en un arreglo, que finalmente puedes mapear como el contenido de texto de cada elemento, si lo que buscas es conservar el HTML interno de cada `li` deberás cambiar `innerText` por `innerHTML`.